# How do I upload a file to wordpress using a custom upload form?

Tags: wordpress, file-upload

I don't want to use Wordpress' built in media uploader.

I have a form (on the frontend) of my site, and I need to allow anyone to upload an image to my uploads folder in wp-content. I've found many tutorials, but they all tell me how to do it with the wordpress uploader. I need to be able to validate what users are uploading.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved. This is the code I used to do it:

In my code:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attachment_id = media_handle_upload('file-upload', $post->ID);
```

In my form:

```
<input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" />
```

Comment: How is this different from the answer mnelson7982 posted?

Comment: It's not. He just wanted the solve checkmark for himself.

Comment: Code in answer from @mnelson7982 was added about 4 months later... Original answer just had a link to WPTuts page.

Answer (score 29):

Does this help?

[WPTuts: Allow users to submit images to your site](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/allow-users-to-submit-images-your-site/)

PHP:

```
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

$attachment_id = media_handle_upload('file-upload', $post->ID);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" />
```

Comment: It did. I dived into the code in that plugin and found my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I'd prefer to write out the code that helped me and accept that as the answer, but I'll upvote your answer for helping me out.