# Front-end drag and drop uploader for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, drag-and-drop

I have to build a frontend drag and drop uploader for wordpress. In a page there will be a area of drag & drop and submit button. when visitor drops his files and click submit button will send to wordpress media library.

I have code of drag and drop of html5. https://github.com/arunkumarsekar/Multiple_file_drag_and_drop_upload

I think my challanging part will be when click submit button how this file will send to the media library? can u give me any idea how to send attach file to the wordpress media library?

Comment: The two answers to this question should solve it for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931870/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-wordpress-using-a-custom-upload-form